# Integrating android street view and google map in my app

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am new to android development. I am working on a project which uses  android street view panorama and Google map

I just noticed that there is no method in street view panorama for querying whether a street view exists in any location before searching for the panorama image, to prevent the app from crashing or showing black screen. Is there a solution to this problem. Again can I use Google map v3 javaScript api any where in android.

You can give the best answer even if it involves learning javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service) is the reference which will help you access the Streetview database of Google. You will be able to find the PANO IDs for the addresses you want to use.
Hope it helped.